# Numba Invalid use of BoundFunction of array.mean

Tags: python, numba

I want to calculate the mean for the second index for each third index.

```
@njit
def mean_some_index(a):
    T = a.shape[2]
    b = np.zeros((T,T))
    for t in range(T):
        b[:, t] = a[:,:,t].mean(axis = 1)
    return b
```

I would use it like

```
a = np.random.randn(5*5*5).reshape((5,5,5))
mean_some_index(a)
```

It is okay without Numba; however, the Numba returns an error saying:

```
resolving callee type: BoundFunction(array.mean for array(float64, 2d, A))
...
File "C:\Users\Mining-Base\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_565300\1191607406.py", line 7:
def mean_some_index(a):
    <source elided>
    for t in range(T):
        b[:, t] = a[:,:,t].mean(axis = 1)
```

I don't quite understand the error and will appreciate for who answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: added the swapped loop version and larger arrays for benchmarking. Also, it seems that `numba` was very helpful for small arrays (hundreds of elements) but less so for large arrays (millions of elements).

Edit2: added parallel code.

---

That's because numba doesn't support arguments for those methods, [see the docs](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html#calculation).

We can still benefit from the speedup by calculating the mean in a loop though.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

rng = np.random.default_rng()


# arr = rng.standard_normal(size=(5, 5, 5))
arr = rng.standard_normal(size=(500, 500, 500))

def np_mean(arr):
    z_dim = arr.shape[2]
    out = np.empty((z_dim, z_dim))
    for ax in range(z_dim):
        out[:, ax] = arr[:, :, ax].mean(axis=1)
    return out


@njit
def nb_mean(arr):
    y_dim, z_dim = arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2]
    out = np.empty((z_dim, z_dim))
    for ax in range(z_dim):
        for idx in range(y_dim):
            out[idx, ax] = arr[:, :, ax][idx].mean()
    return out

@njit
def nb_mean_swapped(arr):
    y_dim, z_dim = arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2]
    out = np.empty((z_dim, z_dim))
    for idx in range(y_dim):
        for ax in range(z_dim):
            out[idx, ax] = arr[:, :, ax][idx].mean()
    return out

@njit(parallel=True)
def nb_mean_swapped_parallel(arr):
    y_dim, z_dim = arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2]
    out = np.empty((z_dim, z_dim))
    for idx in prange(y_dim):
        for ax in prange(z_dim):
            out[idx, ax] = arr[:, :, ax][idx].mean()
    return out
```

```
In [27]: %timeit np_mean(arr)
674 ms ± 23.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [28]: %timeit nb_mean(arr)
606 ms ± 28.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [29]: %timeit nb_mean_swapped(arr)
218 ms ± 23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [30]: %timeit nb_mean_swapped_parallel(arr)
64.3 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: You can swap the two loops so to perform more efficient memory accesses.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the suggestion! I added a different function so that optimization is more apparent. It also seems that numba was particularly helpful for smaller arrays (`5**3 elems`) but that other operations dominate for larger arrays (`500**3 elems`)

Comment: Thank both of you,  Nathan Furnal and Jérôme Richard! It seems that swapping the loops instead of using mean.(axis = n) is more friendly to Numba, am I right? It is similar to wring C codes if so. Also, for large arrays, do you have any suggestions for improving the efficiency? I heard that TensorFlow is good, but I have not given it a try. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mephist Yes, it's akin to C code! Now, Tensorflow won't help you, what you need is to take a better approach to the problem. If we're only talking about sums like in the example above, this code can be parallelized. I added the relevant code in an edit. Now the final result takes a tenth of the time of the initial numpy code.